# Extended Entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Entity B that extends entity A

```
public Class A {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
....
}

public Class B extends A {

private String name;
}
```

When Look into database I see that only table A is created and have both fields from Class A and Class B. I need to create separate table for Class B. 
How can I do that?

**P.S** 
I tried some answers from here stackoverflow but they didn't help me

Comment: You mean, look at JPA documentation at the `@Inheritance` annotation? That is in pretty much all JPA tutorials

Comment: Please elaborate more .. what is the scheme design you are looking to get.. do you also expect hibernate to create the tables automatically for you on startup. Be more precise

Comment: @Neil Stockton I used @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) not it still created 1 table olny

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I need to create 2 different tables. First with name A and second with name B.

Comment: If you used SINGLE_TABLE then it creates 1 table!!! as per the definition of "Single"!! Using JOINED would give more tables ... as per the documentation of `@Inheritance`

Comment: @NeilStockton I tried that too but still receive one table.

Comment: Define "receive". If you start with a clean database, and run a JPA provider with the correct schema generation properties set then it will create one PER entity in the inheritance tree.

Comment: I use "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop" - but still just one table. I tried a lot of combinations of annotations before submitting the question here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class B extends A{
}



@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class InterestBaseSettings {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
.....
}
```

Tested works!

Delete old tables and allow Hibernate to create tables himself.